# I am getting this error: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'employee.PRIMARY'

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I'm studying Java EE with JDBC. I created a simple employee registration form so, when I input the required data, it throws errors and I know it duplicates the primary key (id) in the database. Although, the id column of the database is set up as AUTO_INCREMENT but it still overwrites the same id after each registration. Anyone knows what's wrong with this? Any suggestion is appreciated!

JavaBean:

```
public class Employee {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String address;
    private String contact;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

}
```

EmployeeDao:

```
public class EmployeeDao {

    private String db_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    private String db_user = "root";
    private String db_password = "root";

    public int registerEmployee(Employee employee) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        String sql_insert = "INSERT INTO employee VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        int result = 0;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, db_user, db_password);
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql_insert);
            ps.setInt(1, 1);
            ps.setString(2, employee.getFirstName());
            ps.setString(3, employee.getLastName());
            ps.setString(4, employee.getUsername());
            ps.setString(5, employee.getPassword());
            ps.setString(6, employee.getAddress());
            ps.setString(7, employee.getContact());

            System.out.println(ps);

            result = ps.executeUpdate();

            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The page that shows a successful message:

```
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="employee" class="jsp.jdbc.javaBean.Employee"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="employee" />

<%
    EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
    int status = employeeDao.registerEmployee(employee);
    if(status > 0){
        out.println("You have successfully registered");
    }
%>
<br/><br/>
<a href="EmployeeRegistrationFrom.html">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an ID apparently. This is your code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql_insert);
ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setString(2, employee.getFirstName());
ps.setString(3, employee.getLastName());
ps.setString(4, employee.getUsername());
ps.setString(5, employee.getPassword());
ps.setString(6, employee.getAddress());
ps.setString(7, employee.getContact());
```

Isn't this the ID?

```
ps.setInt(1, 1);
```

Remove this line of code.

Don't forget to reorder your parameters for your insert query and - as a good practice - use the column names in your insert statement (as pointed out in the comment below by Luke Woodward):

```
String sql_insert = "INSERT INTO employee (firstname, lastname, username, password, address, contact) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, db_user, db_password);
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql_insert);
ps.setString(1, employee.getFirstName());
ps.setString(2, employee.getLastName());
ps.setString(3, employee.getUsername());
ps.setString(4, employee.getPassword());
ps.setString(5, employee.getAddress());
ps.setString(6, employee.getContact());
```

Adjust the column names as you have them in your table.

Also, as an advice, you might want to hash the password before inserting it into the database. Storing passwords in plain text in the database [isn't advised](https://medium.com/maclaurin-group/what-is-clear-text-passwords-and-why-you-shouldnt-store-them-e61c604b1fb7).

Comment: I followed your suggestion but It throws this error now: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @user13738974: add the column names into your `INSERT` statement, i.e. `INSERT INTO employee (firstname, lastname, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)`.  Adjust this for what the actual column names are in your table. It's a good idea to always specify the column names for `INSERT` statements: otherwise you run the risk that code that works in development fails in production because the columns in the same table in different databases happen to be in a different order.

Comment: @Luke Woodward  yeah, this is an good advise, thank you. And the code is working properly now.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: Nice catch. I missed that :). If you don't mind, I'll update my answer to include it for people that might not read the comments.

Comment: @Bogdan: that's fine, please feel free to update your answer.